# How can i send different type of Notificaton with FirebaseCloud sendNotification Function

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-functions

I have this function which sends notification once there is certain change in my Db node. but i want to send multiple type of notifications for different actions. but when i deploy my function it overrides prior one and then i have tried all functions in single script  but its not working properly

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/All_Users/{reciever_user_id}/CouponsUsedNotifications/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context ) => {
    const reciever_user_id = context.params.reciever_user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
    console.log('Notification sent to : ', reciever_user_id)
    if(!data.after.val()){
            console.log('Notification Deleted : ', notification_id)

            return null;
    }
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/All_Users/${reciever_user_id}/Credentials/device_token`).once('value');
    return deviceToken.then(result =>
        {
            const token_id = result.val()
            const payload = {
                notification:
                {
                    title: "Coupon Used",
                    body: `Your Coupon has been used..!!`,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            }

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(
                Response => {
                    console.log('Notification Sent')
                }
            )
        })})
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/All_Users/{reciever_user_id}/UserApprovalNotifications/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context ) => {
    const reciever_user_id = context.params.reciever_user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    console.log('Notification sent to : ', reciever_user_id)

    if(!data.after.val()){
            console.log('Notification Deleted : ', notification_id)

            return null;
    }
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/All_Users/${reciever_user_id}/Credentials/device_token`).once('value');
    return deviceToken.then(result =>
        {
            const token_id = result.val()
            const payload = {
                notification:
                {
                    title: "Profile Approved",
                    body: `Your Profile has been Approved..!!`,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(
                Response => {
                    console.log('Notification Sent')
                }
            )
        })})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution...as i am not javascript developer thats why i was struggling but the solution i found is pretty simple. just install the files to new folder.

```
exports.sendNotification = function.
```

the sendNotification is the name of function just change it and deploy it